# I cannot access but but wp-admin works normally

Tags: user-access

anything is wrong with my website: `buhehe.de` it is down, but i can access `buhehe.de/wp-admin` and other websites which are hosted on some server are working. Is anything wrong with plugins? I installed many plugins. HOw can i find where is a problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have try to to deactivate all plugins, one by one. Then change your theme to standard (let say, twentyseventeen). This procedure will help you to find the source of the problem.